# .push is not a function. (DISCORD.JS)

Tags: node.js, arrays, discord.js

Trying to make a cooldown on message events when giving a user xp. Running into an issue where `cooldowns.push() is not a fucntion` I have done googling and what I have found is that I need to have an array but to my understanding a `Discord.Collection` is the same thing.

I need this to check the collection to see if the users ID is in there, but if it is not add it for 3 seconds then remove it.

```
const config = require(`../settings/config.js`)
const prefix = config.prefix
const { createConnection } = require(`mysql`)
const mysql = require("../settings/mysql.js")
const Discord  = require(`discord.js`)
let cooldowns = new Discord.Collection()

module.exports = async (client, message, member) => {

    if (!cooldowns.has(message.author.id)) {
        cooldowns.push(message.author.id)
    }

    setTimeout(() => cooldowns.delete(message.author.id), 3000)
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Push is an array method. `cooldowns` is a collection which extends Map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/collections.html#array-like-methods:

> Discord.js comes with this utility class known as Collection. It extends JavaScript's native Map class, so it has all the features of Map and more!

So no, it's not an array, it's a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set). In your case I think you'd want to use:

```
cooldowns.set(message.author.id, 1)
```